# Ignore spaces in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to split a string in individual words using vector in C++. So I would like to know how to ignore spaces in vector, if user put more than one space between words in string.

How would I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout<<"Sentence: ";
    string sentence;
    getline(cin,sentence);

    vector<string> my;
    int start=0;
    unsigned int end=sentence.size();

unsigned int temp=0;

while(temp<end){
    int te=sentence.find(" ",start);
    temp=te;
    my.push_back(sentence.substr(start, temp-start));
    start=temp+1;
}

unsigned int i;
    for(i=0 ; i<my.size() ; i++){

        cout<<my[i]<<endl;

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a `std::regex` or even better `std::stringstream`.

Comment: why not simply using `cin >> string` and iterate ?

Comment: I would indent code properly to be clearer for people trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) like follows:

```
std::string sentence;
std::getline(std::cin,sentence);
std::istringstream iss(sentence);
std::vector<std::string> my;
std::string word;
while(iss >> word) {
    my.push_back(word);
}
```

Any whitespaces will be ignored and skipped automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Four things:

1. When reading input from a stream into astring using the overloaded `>>` operator, then it automatically separates on white-space. I.e. it reads "words".
2. There exists an input stream that uses a string as the input, [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).
3. You can use iterators with streams, like e.g. [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).
4. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) have a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking a pair of iterators.

That means your code could simply be

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::istringstream istr(line);

std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(istr),
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

After this, the vector `words` will contain all the "words" from the input line.

You can easily print the "words" using [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) and [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(begin(words), end(words),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the vector directly using the [std::istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) which skips white spaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello World  Lorem Ipsum  The    Quick Brown Fox";
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::vector<std::string> vec {std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };
    for (const auto& el : vec) {
        std::cout << el << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which divides given sentence into words.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

std::vector<std::string> divideSentence(const std::string& sentence) {
    std::stringstream stream(sentence);
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;
    while(stream >> word) {
        words.push_back(std::move(word));
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Reducing double, triple etc. spaces in string is a problem you'll encounter again and again. I've always used the following very simple algorithm:

Pseudocode:

```
while "  " in string:
    string.replace("  ", " ")
```

After the while loop, you know your string only has single spaces since multiple consecutive spaces were compressed to singles.

Most languages allow you to search for a substring in a string and most languages have the ability to run `string.replace()` so it's a useful trick.

Comment: The question is how to do it in C++ so posting a solution in a different language or pseudocode doesn't seem like a solution. Besides, `std::string::replace` doesn't work that way so the code lacks a few important details like using `find`. Also, although this trick works it has poor performance.

Comment: His question is "So I would like to know how to ignore spaces in vector, if user put more than one space between words in string.". That's what I've answered in the simplest and shortest fashion. Comment about performance is irrelevant.